# Notation for appending 2 submatrices

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a matrix $M$ with $i$ rows and $(e+n)$ columns:  $M_{i,e+n}$

I would like to express that $M_{i,e+n}$ is the result of appending $M_{i,e}$ and $M_{i,n}$

What is the algebraic notation to express this, i.e. the "append" operation??

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $M=(M_e, M_n)$, where $M$ is $i\times (e+n)$, $M_e$ is $i\times e$ and $M_n$ is $i \times n$?

Comment: Yes, I mean precisely that.  Is it the common notation to just separate the submatrices with a comma? If so how would you for example  indicate that Mn is obtained by extracting Me from M?

Comment: Yes, or without the comma. See the first example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix.

Comment: Great! Thanks for helping